# Как правильно указать название Дома культуры

Tags: прописная-строчная, прописная

Подскажите, как правильно указать название Дома культуры: Кривошеевский сельский Дом культуры или Кривошеевский сельский дом культуры; Томаровский Дом культуры или Томаровский дом культуры. Интересует именно то, какая буква указывается в слове Дом культуры после ссылки на населённый пункт, - прописная или срочная?

Answer (score 1):

С прописной буквы пишется **первое слово и собственные имена** в названиях зрелищных предприятий и учреждений культуры, например: Московский театр оперетты, Государственный центральный театр кукол, Театр революционной сатиры (теперь - Московский академический театр им. Вл. Маяковского), Театральное училище им. М. С. Щепкина при Малом театре, Школа-студия им. Вл. И. Немировича-Данченко при МХАТе СССР, Краснознаменный им. А. В. Александрова ансамбль песни и пляски Советской Армии, Концертный зал им. П. И. Чайковского, Колонный зал Дома союзов, Центральный музей В. И. Ленина, Государственный музей Л. Н. Толстого, Музей народного творчества, Дом-музей А. П. Чехова, Политехнический музей, Государственная публичная историческая библиотека РСФСР, Дворец пионеров (Дворцы пионеров), Центральный Дворец пионеров (но: районный Дворец пионеров - первое слово не входит в составное название), Дворец культуры Метростроя, Дом офицера (Дома офицеров), **Дом учителя (также: Московский Дом учителя; но: Московский городской дом учителя - при наличии второго определения)**, Центральный ордена Ленина парк культуры...
Розенталь Д.Э. Прописная или строчная.

Соответственно ваши примеры:

Кривошеевский сельский дом культуры; Томаровский Дом культуры.